# Append item to opaque linked list handler in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Im beggining with linked list in C, and I found some problems where (if I understood well) manipulate linked lists without knowing internal structre (fields)!

Is it possible to append/remove an item in a linked list **without knowledge of it's internal structure**(opaque)  given a pointer to the linked list?

Edit (adding details).

So the problem is to create a set of functions to manipulate linked lists, given a handler on the linked list as a parameter which is declared in the follwoing way :

```
typedef struct list *handler;
```

so for example I created a function to create a linked list :

```
handler ListCreate()
{
    handler list = (handler)malloc(sizeof(handler));
    if(!list)
    {
        printf("can not allocate memory \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return list;
}
```

but when it comes to appending, Im just blocked and I thought it can't be done, but maybe I'm wrong.

So this is the prototype of the function :

```
int ListAppend(handler list, void *item)
```

Comment: Generally, any question starting with "is it possible to do..." can be answered with "yes". With that said, is it the *list* that is the opaque structure, or the data you want to add to the list?

Comment: both, the list is opaque and the data is void*..

Comment: And now to the hard question: What is your problem? Do you have a set of functions for such a list that you just want to use? Or are you supposed to create a set of functions and structures to be able to handle this? What have you tried? What problems do you have with your attempt? Do you have a [mcve] of your attempt to show us? And perhaps it's time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Just updated the post! thanks :)

Comment: Since `handler` is a pointer, `malloc(sizeof(handler))` is wrong. That will only allocate memory enough for the *pointer*, not the structure it points to. This is one of the dangers of using type-aliases of pointers. Use `sizeof *list` instead.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the person implementing the linked list functions not to have access to the internals of the list structure. How did you end up in that situation? Are you sure you have not misunderstood what you are tasked to do? Or are there other functions given to you that can manipulate the list?

Comment: That's the task header 

// Linked list implementation skeleton
//
// This is a linked list implementation, although the user does not require
// any knowledge of the internal structure and implementation of the list.
//
// Items in the linked list are passed through as void pointers and cannot
// be NULL (this is used as a special result in many functions)

// The linked list handle
typedef struct linked_list_s *linked_list_t;

Comment: So I think that's what im asked for + there is no other functions to use.

Comment: It means you need to define the list structure. The opaque pointer is returned to the calling code. It's opaque to the users of the code. Not opaque to you the implementer of the code. This is a very standard pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do something similar, but I had to figure it out myself. The idea is to make an opaque object interface, and then give access to attributes of the implementation file by casting using a switch statement. I'm doing it this way to follow the dependency inversion principle. All of the code is in a single file to show that it compiles, but the three comment lines //interface, //dependency, and //context can be broken into different files so you can try different implementations of the dependency file without having to change the interface file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//interface
typedef enum {
    DEP1,
    DEP2
} Type;

typedef struct Interface{
    struct Interface* ptr;
    void* data;
    int (*getConcreteStuff)(struct Interface*, Type t);
} Interface;

//dependency
typedef struct {
    int concreteStuff1;
} Dependency1;

typedef struct {
    int concreteStuff2;
} Dependency2;


static int getConcreteStuff(Interface* interface, Type t) {
    switch(t){
        case DEP1:
            return ((Dependency1*) interface->data)->concreteStuff1;
            break;
        case DEP2:
            return ((Dependency2*) interface->data)->concreteStuff2;
            break;
    }
}

Interface Dependency1_new(Interface* ptr){
    Dependency1* d = malloc(sizeof(*d));
    d->concreteStuff1 = 1;
    struct Interface x = {ptr, d, getConcreteStuff };
    return x;
}

Interface Dependency2_new(Interface* ptr){
    Dependency2* d = malloc(sizeof(*d));
    d->concreteStuff2 = 2;
    struct Interface y = {ptr, d, getConcreteStuff };
    return y;
}

//context
typedef struct {
    Interface i;
} Context;

void Context_doSomething(Context* ctx, Type t){
    printf("%d\n", ctx->i.getConcreteStuff(&ctx->i, t));
}

int main(){
    Context ctx1 = { Dependency1_new(NULL) };
    Context_doSomething(&ctx1, DEP1);
    Context ctx2 = { Dependency2_new(&ctx1.i) };
    Context_doSomething(&ctx2, DEP2);
    Context ctx3 = { *ctx2.i.ptr };
    Context_doSomething(&ctx3, DEP1);
    return 1;
}
```